# how to force RTL on UITabBarCountroller in IOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

i am building an app in english , and i want to support Arabic also

**I am not using any default Localization or internationalization in my app because i don't need them instead, i am doing it manually**

every thing is perfect but i can not figure out hoe to make the UITabBar go from the right to left
**I don't want the whole app to go from rtl , only the UITabBarController**

ex : my tabBar now is like this :

**tab1 : home
tab2 : search
tab3 : settings**

when the user change language inside the app , i want the tab bar to go like this :

**tab1 : settings
tab2 : search
tab3 : Home**

**note that i am using storyBoard to make my UI**

thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2):

I Found the answer to my problem

**it turned out that you can force RTL or LTR on any specific view like this :**

```
YourView.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft  // RTL
YourView.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight  // LTR
```